# How to conect client to server through ad-hoc network by socket

Tags: c++, windows, wifi, adhoc

I read similar posts here, but no one is really helpfull, so I ask same for Windows.

On server side we create ad-hoc network and connect to it using ad-hoc api, on client side we get enumeration of all available ad-hoc networks and connect to proper one.

Now on server side we just create listening socket, we don't need to specify any ip address.
But on client side we must know server ip address to create connection socket.

I know that socket layer is independent from higher level (ad-hoc), but it's not the answer.  The goal: get ip address of server that created ad-hoc network on client that is currently connected to that network. I don't want to use other libraries like managed wi-fi.

Maybe there is some win api function to get list of ip addresses associated with ad-hoc network, some ip address range?  I don't quite understand all specifics (and hardly will do, considering education process), so just point me in right direction.  The language is not the matter, may it be C# or C++.
Thanks.

Comment: All of the "ad-hoc" make your question confusing.  Use gethostbyname() to map a machine name to IP address.

Comment: In general, there is no way to get a list of all IP addresses associated with *any* network.  I've seen three approaches to solve your problem however: 1) Everyone has predefined static, non-conflicting addresses, 2) *Someone* decides to listen to a predefined address, maybe after asking if anyone is already listening and becomes the "leader", managing additional address assignment, or 2) The peers in the network use broadcast messages to discover each other negotiate IP addresses